# JavaMail not correctly decoding ISO-8859-1 mail

Tags: java, jakarta-mail, iso-8859-1

I'm receiving a message from an IMAP server which is encoded using `Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit` using JavaMail. As far as I can tell, the server correctly outputs the message and it can be decoded, as both `telnet` and Thunderbird display the message which contains the German phrase "Mit freundlichen Grüßen" ("Sincerely yours") exactly as-is.

However, when I retrieve the `MimeMessage` using JavaMail and get its `InputStream` using the following code, it returns `Mit freundlichen GrÃ¼Ãen` (with one invisible `0x9F` byte after the second `Ã`):

```
MimeMessage msg = imapFolder.getMessages() [0]; // Just for demo purposes
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder ();
String line;

try (
  BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader (
    new InputStreamReader (msg.getInputStream ())
  )
) {
  while ((line = reader.readLine ()) != null) {
    builder.append (line).append ("\n");
  }
} catch (IOException e) {
  // ...
}
```

The situation gets kind of "worse" if I try to get the mail's contents using `MimeMessage`'s `getRawInputStream ()` function; it then returns `Mit freundlichen GrÃÂ¼ÃÂen` (with invisible `0x83` bytes after the two `Ã` and an invisible `0x9F` byte after `Â`).

However, as far as I can tell, both functions should return the correct message.

Should I be doing

```
builder.append (line.getBytes ("ISO-8859-1")).append ("\n");
```

or

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader (
  new InputStreamReader (msg.getInputStream (), Charset.forName ("ISO-8859-1"))
);
```

(but that didn't work either when I tried) or am I (and/or the server) doing something else blatantly wrong?

Comment: What's the header of the e-mail?

Comment: `Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8; format=flowed` as well as `Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit` (however, I just noticed that Thunderbird displays something pretty similar when I click on "Display source code", but not the exact same string I get)

Comment: `new InputStreamReader (msg.getInputStream (), "ISO-8859-1")`

Comment: The fact it decodes to `GrÃ¼Ãen` suggests it is in UTF-8, and `GrÃÂ¼ÃÂen` suggests multiple incorrect encoding/decoding cycles were involved.

Comment: Thought so also, because Thunderbird displays it like that, but how do I get the proper UTF-8 string?

Comment: Why are you even using `getInputStream` (and then using an `InputStreamReader` without explicitly specifying a character set)? If you properly use JavaMail, you shouldn't have this problem, because then you'd use `getContent()` on the right part and get it decoded correctly by JavaMail (at least: assuming it is correctly encoded in the first place).

Comment: @MarkRotteveel please make that an answer so that I can +1 it

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Indeed. I was using streams because I felt they were easier to use (instead of iterating over the different parts), but *apparently they aren't*...

Answer (score 0):

When you've read a line, it's too late to try a conversion. Use `new InputStreamReader (msg.getInputStream (), "ISO-8859-1")`.

Comment: However, this results in `Mit freundlichen GrÃÂ¼ÃÂen` (the same result I got with `getRawInputStream ()`), which I do not understand. I understand that the charset should be applied to the `InputStreamReader`, just as you said, but don't know why it simply does not work.

Comment: Perhaps the data is really utf-8 data and the headers incorrectly represent it as iso-8859-1 data?  Try using "utf-8" with the InputStreamReader and see if that helps.

Comment: @AlexanderLeithner don't use either of those then. Use `getContent`.